# How to create mongoose schema dynamically?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an app that works on node.js with MongoDB and mongoose. My app simply sends/deletes/edits form data and for that, I have such mongoose model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('appForm', {
    User_id : {type: String},
    LogTime : {type: String},
    feeds : [   
    {
        Name: {type: String},
        Text : {type: String},
    }
    ]
});
```

and that works just fine!

Now, I would like to add a function to the form so that the user can add a field(or fields) to form and enter a text in it and post it.
Creating that dynamic functionality on the client side is no problem but I understand that my mongoose.model has to be correctly structured. 
My question is: how do I add that variable values(dynamically created form data name and its text) to mongoose schema?

I see that using `strict: false` and `Schema.Types.Mixed` is advised. however, I can't figure out...
What I have tried:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var feedSchema = new Schema({strict:false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('appForm', feedSchema);
```

Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Apply the `strict: false` option to your existing schema definition by supplying it as a second parameter to the `Schema` constructor:

```
var appFormSchema = new Schema({
    User_id : {type: String},
    LogTime : {type: String},
    feeds : [new Schema({
        Name: {type: String},
        Text : {type: String}
    }, {strict: false})
    ]
}, {strict: false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('appForm', appFormSchema);
```

If you want to leave `feeds` as fully schemaless, that's where you can used `Mixed`:

```
var appFormSchema = new Schema({
    User_id : {type: String},
    LogTime : {type: String},
    feeds : [Schema.Types.Mixed]
}, {strict: false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('appForm', appFormSchema);
```

Comment: That code works and posts default form data:user_id,LogTime and feeds array and its object but as I add another property into feeds array like:customText, it doesn't update that customText but the rest...I ll search where I am still doing something wrong..thanks anyway!

Comment: If you want to add arbitrary properties to `feeds`, then the option needs to be set on that embedded schema as well.  See the updated answer.

Comment: YES!!!:) second option is exactly what I am trying to do for hours! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnnyHK can you please help and tell how to write a schema for inserting the json data into such appFormSchema ?
I mean i am sending such complex json from my app to server, where rest api uses my predefined model schema to insert the data .Thing is while inserting i have diff number of json object in the feeds array so how to map them in db?

Answer (score 1):

In the **latest** version of Mongoose, you can use something like this

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const assetSchema = new Schema(
  { name: { type: String, required: true } },
  { timestamps: { createdAt: "created_at", updatedAt: "updated_at" } }
);

const Asset = mongoose.model("Asset", assetSchema);

const addDynamicField = (fieldName, type) => {
  assetSchema.add({ [fieldName]: { type, default: null } });
};

module.exports = { Asset, addDynamicField };
```

we can set `propertyName` and it's `type`

Eg:

```js
propertyName = "age"
propertyType = "Number"

addDynamicField(propertyName, propertyType);
```

This will create a **dynamic property** in the schema and also there is no need of using `{strict: false}`.