# what is the best practice to create nested model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Im new to mongoDB and mongoose, familiar with very basic model Schema.
The problem I have is how to create nested object which is linking with dynamic keys.
This is the data structure, I wanted to have.
As you can see, each task in tasks object has dynamic key that is the same as own id. columns has same structure, and columnOrder store the column's id at same time. how to deal with this data structure? I guess I should use objectId ref, but not sure.

```
export const fakeData = {
  tasks: {
    "task-1": { id: "task-1", content: "take out the garbage" },
    "task-2": { id: "task-2", content: "Watch movie" },
    "task-3": { id: "task-3", content: "Catch my phone" },
    "task-4": { id: "task-4", content: "cookDinner" }
  },
  columns: {
    "column-1": {
      id: "column-1",
      title: "To do",
      taskIds: ["task-1", "task-2", "task-3", "task-4"]
    },
    "column-2": {
      id: "column-2",
      title: "In progress",
      taskIds: []
    },
    "column-3": {
      id: "column-3",
      title: "Done",
      taskIds: []
    }
  },
  columnOrder: ["column-1", "column-2", "column-3"]
};
```

I really appreciate someone teach me how to handle this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create mongoose schema dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166463/how-to-create-mongoose-schema-dynamically)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I actuary read this, but couldn't figure out how directly link key and object Id dynamically. 
Let's say, 'column-1' is my key and also object Id of column schema, which is nested in columns. My question is how to change the value dynamically.

Comment: *change the value dynamically.* --> Do you mean to say update in DB ?

Comment: yes. the ideal case is the key changes automatically changes in the DB