# How to create dynamic schema in mongodb with validation using mongoose ORM?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to allocate a nested Schema for the **setting** field of the Chatbot schema and it should dynamically select the schema based on key field value. How can I achieve that as the setting for each bot is going to be different and it should also be validated.

```
// External Dependencies
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

// Schema
const Chatbot = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        key: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            enum: [`CHATBOT_1`, `CHATBOT_2`]
        },
        setting: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)

// Exporting Module
export default mongoose.model('Chatbot', Chatbot)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create dynamic schema you can use this [How to create mongoose schema dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166463/how-to-create-mongoose-schema-dynamically) with [pre('save') method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) with mongoose and validate your data before saving it.